# Can I build a temporary driveway ramp over a new concrete curb?

Tags: driveway

My street is being redone and the road crew poured the new curbs yesterday and the bossman says I can't get out.

I notice that the level of the earth of my lawn is above the level of the poured curb. Would i be able to use two separate 2x6 boards and lean them over the curb against the lawn and use them as a makeshift ramp to get my vehicle out?

Comment: Doesn't worth the hassle man call Uber where ever you are going

Comment: Were you given some advance notice that you wouldn't be able to drive over the curb for some period of time?

Comment: Give the bossman $50 and see if he changes his mind. If he's union, $100.

Answer (score 1):

If the boards flex and bend under the load and crush the green concrete curb, you will be responsible for the full cost of the road crew returning to the site, removing the mess, and pouring new curbs.

Right now only the bossman thinks you're stupid. You don't want to hear the same thing from a judge.

If you can find some cement blocks or other firm braces, you can support the boards right next to the curb. Make sure it can't wobble. You're still taking a chance, though.

Don't do this job alone. You should have at least two helpers, one to watch the ramp as you drive onto it and stop you if it shifts or bends, and the other to hold your beer.

Comment: It needs to be said that concrete blocks only reliably support load in one direction, and only if they themselves are firmly supported. Solid bricks would be better.